# Is the usage of ‘that’ in “I miss the day that I was trouble-free” ok, or must it use ‘when’?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, relative-clauses, subordinate-clauses, noun-complement-clauses

In this sentence:

> I miss the days **that** I was trouble-free.

I know it would be correct if *that* were replaced by *when*, but would *that* also be correct here?

Also, I have this faint feeling that there are two types of clauses that denote the time of occurrences:

1. one type in which neither *that* nor *when* is needed
    (e.g., *the day she left*), and
2. the other type in which *when* is necessary
    (e.g., *the days when I had to walk home alone after school*).

I think in the first type, the action described is often transient,
whereas in the second type, the action usually spans a period of time.

I’m confused and didn’t find the answer after several searches.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

John Lawler wrote:

*That*, as a relative pronoun (*We know the man that she saw*), or as a complementizer (*We know that she saw him*), occurs only in tensed clauses, which are otherwise independent, except for the machinery involving *that*.

...

The question of which wh-words can be swapped with *that* is difficult and varies a lot from person to person. Most English speakers wouldn't notice if *that* were used instead of *when*, since it can be used for *where*, *why*, and *how*. But some folks prefer *when* and disprefer *that* in this situation.

Comment: Yes, I'm in the 'when' camp here. Though after 'the times', 'that' or Ø might work better for me. 'I miss those times the train would stop at the local halt.'

Comment: I don't know about that, but when I think about it, I tend to agree with @EdwinAshworth: that or nothing. Actually, when I don't think about it. As a native speaker you "feel" it when something seems wrong to you — you don't think about it.

Comment: My intuition is that "that" is more suitable if there were isolated days spaced in time defined by some condition ("On the days that I missed the bus, I begged my neighbour for a lift"), and "when" is more suitable if referring to a time period ("the days when I was young"), but this might just be personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

> I miss the days that I was trouble-free.
>
> I know it would be correct if "that" is replaced by "when," but can "that" also be correct?

The short answer is "Yes." The *that* subordinate clauses in question fall into three main categories:

**The relative clause**, which is basically adjectival:
*He saw the man that robbed the bank.* In which the whole of the clause is an object and "that robbed the bank" specifies/defines/qualifies "the man".

**The content clause**, which is basically a noun clause:
*"John told me that the man robbed the bank."* in which "that the man robbed the bank" gives the contents of John's speech.

**The adverbial clause**
*"He died that others might live"* in which "that others might live" defines the purpose of "He died".

**The adjectival clause**
I miss the days {**when** I was trouble-free} is simply adjectival = **upon which** I was trouble-free. = "I miss {my trouble-free days}

*I miss {the days that I was trouble-free.}* does not differ significantly from *I miss {the days when I was trouble-free.} as they both equate to *"I miss {my trouble-free days}